# How to update git in cmder after updating it internally

Tags: git, cmder

How to make changes after updating the git from the terminal with

`$ git-update-git-for-windows`

I want 2 know if how do you update such git inside cmder because in my git bash I see this :

[image]

But when I go into cmder I see this thing

[image]

How do you make this two reflect with each other..

Comment: Run both `which git` and `where git` in git-bash and cmd. They may use different git installations.

Comment: yeah , you're right they're not the same so should I move them ? ?

Comment: how 2 point cmder to point it to that specific location.. ? ?

Comment: Try `echo %path%` in cmd and `echo $PATH` in git-bash to see if both git installation paths are in `%path%` and `$PATH`. Maybe you can uninstall one of them, and add or keep the left in both `%path%` and `$PATH` so that cmd and git-bash will use the same git.

Comment: `cmd` or `cmde`r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [seen here](https://superuser.com/a/906092/141), you can update the PATH of cmder with its user startup script, in `cmder\config\user-profile.cmd`.

```
@set PATH=<path_to_Git>\bin;%PATH%
```

You can also use the [cmder system menu](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Setting-up-Environment-Variables) (`System Preferences`, then click on `Advanced system settings → Environment Variables`.)

In the OP's case:

```
@echo off @set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\;%PATH%
```

The idea is to add in front of the `%PATH%` the *parent* folder (bin) of the correct `git.exe` (2.24), not the executable itself.

Comment: The one you get when you type `where git` in your CMD, where git 2.24 is.

Comment: This is inside the file , is it alright ?`@echo off
@set PATH=<C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe>\bin;%PATH%
`

Comment: Yes, except remove the <> and the bin\git.exe, and keep the final \bin.

Comment: Still the same friend

Comment: I wrote it like this `@echo off
@set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe\bin;%PATH%
`

Comment: @TheBAST I have edited the answer with the correct line.